# Подгружаемые части android приложения

Tags: android

Добрый день всем.

Возможно кому то попадалась подобная реализация приложения:

Есть исходное приложение, с минимальным функционалом. По желанию пользователя, можно подгружать "модули" обеспечивающие тот или иной функционал.

Я сначала подумал сделать свои библиотеки, и потом их подгружать. но тогда не совсем ясно как я смогу к ним обращаться потом.

Если кому попадалось описние, как подобное сделать, то буду благодарен за ссылочку.

Пример: Приложение "Приват24". Там можно подгрузить модуль читающий смс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [`DexClassLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html).
2. Если же есть желание и возможность выпускать плагины в виде отдельных элементов Google Play, то плагин может общаться с хост-приложением (и наоборот) с помощью `Intent` и `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Спасибо. Плагины будут грузится не через ГуглПлэй. 

Такой вопрос, если подгружатся будет активити какая нибудь? ее можно в манифесте зарегистрировать как то динамичиски?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, нет способа это осуществить. Если плагины будут предоставлять не только некоторую функциональность, но и `activity`, то единственным выходом будут плагины в виде отдельных apk, т.е. второй пункт в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html). Насчет того, чтобы хранить код в них - не уверен, по моему нельзя, но вынести туда ресурсы и ассеты - самое оно.

А чтобы подгрузить модуль реализующий доп.функционал, то архитектура Android приложений изначально приспособлена для этого:

1. Создаете приложение (можно без UI интерфейса) реализующее какой-нибудь `Service` или `Intent` - соответствующим образом оформляете в манифесте
2. Далее из своего приложения вызываете сервис/интент

Пример, можно посмотреть [здесь](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.ru/2010/06/plugins.html)